# Mutual TLS with Quarkus

Tags: java, tls1.2, quarkus

I've been able to get an existing application mostly working under Quarkus. The original application uses Undertow and RESTEasy and all endpoints use mutual TLS. Working with Undertow directly, it's relatively straightforward to get mTLS working. But doing the same is Quarkus is not so obvious.

I'm intrigued by what Quarkus is doing, but it seems to lack lower-level access to some of the internals for situations like mTLS and likely other scenarios. Is this type of configuration workable today, is it planned, or is that type of use case not part of the Quarkus charter? Part of me feels like creating a custom Undertow extension, but it would be a lot simpler to simply extend the existing extension. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the information in https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl-guide help at alll?

Comment: That covers 1-way TLS. I'm looking to configure the underlying web server to require that the client present a certificate. That is easy to do with Undertow directly, but not as obvious with Quarkus.

Comment: I suggest you send an email to the mailing list then

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to figure this out, too, and while this isn't mentioned in any Quarkus guide, the configuration options are there:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-file
- https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-password
- https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.ssl.client-auth

Comment: I saw that but I'm trying to not use static Keystores. We use Yahoo Athenz, which uses mutual TLS for authorization. Athenz will refresh the SSLContext every 2 hours or so and replaces the certs on-disk. It also uses PEM-encoded certs, not Keystore, so we build the Keystore & SSLContext programatically.

I'd like to be able to have lower-level access to manage the creation of the SSLContext. We actually use Undertow today and use Athenz with no problem. The issue I have is that it is not clear how to get this level of access in Quarkus, even though it's still using Undertow under the hood.

Comment: Actually inside Quarkus, Undertow only plays the role of servlet container. It often isn't even present. All the HTTP transport is based on Vert.x. Whether it's possible to access those internals, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a quickstart sample around Mutual TLS with Quarkus.

On server side, the properties to enable are:

**SSL configuration**

```
quarkus.ssl.native=true
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=...
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=...
```

**Truststore configuration to validate the Client certificate**

```
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-file=...
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.trust-store-password=...
```

**Activate client configuration**

```
quarkus.http.ssl.client-auth=required
```

On client side, because Quarkus uses MicroProfile Rest specification, you need to define the following properties:

**Server endpoint**

```
org.acme.restclient.tck.GreetingService/mp-rest/url=...
```

**Truststore configuration**

```
org.acme.restclient.tck.GreetingService/mp-rest/trustStore=...
org.acme.restclient.tck.GreetingService/mp-rest/trustStorePassword=...
```

**Client certificate**

```
org.acme.restclient.tck.GreetingService/mp-rest/keyStore=...
org.acme.restclient.tck.GreetingService/mp-rest/keyStorePassword=...
```

You can find everything on https://github.com/openlab-red/quarkus-mtls-quickstart